# How do default and static methods work in java 8 interfaces?

Tags: java, java-8, jls

I have been trying to get my head around on how actually do the **default** and **static** methods work in java 8?

consider the following interface:

```
public interface Car {

  default void drive() {
    System.out.println("Default Driving");
  }

  static int getWheelCount(){
    return wheelCount;
  }

  int wheelCount = 7;
}
```

and the following implementation:

```
public class Benz implements Car { }
```

Now if I go to my main method and write:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Car car = new Benz();
  car.drive();
  System.out.println(Car.getWheelCount());
  System.out.println(Car.wheelCount);
}
```

I would like to know what is really going on under the hood:

1. Does the default method get called upon the instance of `Car` in a way which is similar to how abstract classes work?
2. What new features/modifications did the language need in order to support default and static methods in interfaces?
3. I know that by default, all the fields in an interface are by default `public static final`, is that in any way related to my above questions.
4. With the introduction of default methods, do we have the need of abstract classes anymore?

**P.S.**
Please feel free to edit the question to make it more useful for fellow SO users.

Comment: In order for your questions to be helpful to other users, please limit them to one per post.

Comment: The 4 questions at the end seem to be all related in respect that they refer to default methods and interfaces. I don't see the point in including them in separate posts and makes more sense to group them together.

Comment: @Kerry: the fourth question clearly is a duplicate of several already existing questions. This already demonstrates why it is bad to ask several entirely different questions at once. All questions tagged with [tag:java-8] are related in respect that they refer to java 8, still there is a point in writing different questions in separate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Java interface default methods will help us in extending interfaces without having the fear of breaking implementation classes.

> What if those computer-controlled car manufacturers add new
>   functionality, such as flight, to their cars? These manufacturers
>   would need to specify new methods to enable other companies (such as
>   electronic guidance instrument manufacturers) to adapt their software
>   to flying cars. Where would these car manufacturers declare these new
>   flight-related methods? If they add them to their original interfaces,
>   then programmers who have implemented those interfaces would have to
>   rewrite their implementations. If they add them as static methods,
>   then programmers would regard them as utility methods, not as
>   essential, core methods.

3. AFAIK, *static methods* aren't needed to override, so being `final` of static methods is coherent. Overriding depends on having an instance of a class. A *static method* is not associated with any instance of a class so the concept is not applicable. However, *default methods* must have overrideable property as I quote above.
4. *Can you have default ctor, private fields, instance members in an interface in Java 8?*

---

I like to use thanks to default methods,

```
list.sort(ordering);
```

instead of

```
Collections.sort(list, ordering);
```

Comment: fair enough, could you please elaborate on what did they do to enable java to have default implementations in interfaces?
I accept all the other explanations.

Comment: Are you asking that _"how they add/implement the feature to Java"_  or _"what they gain by adding the feature to Java(I've answered already)"_ ? @AditA.Pillai

Answer (score 1):

See it seems you're a bit confused between abstract classes and interfaces.

**Abstract Classes:**

Within abstract classes we can abstract methods and non abstract methods. For abstract method me need not have a method definition in place and for non-abstract method we need to have a method body in place.

A class an extend only on abstract class.

**Interfaces:**

Interfaces in good old times(Java 7) never had a method body, with the advent of java 8 we can specify the method body with default keyword.

A class can implement multiple interfaces.

So when we need a class to conform to the features of two entities, we might make use of the interfaces. Now with default key-word, we get a default method body(of the methods of the interfaces) for our class provided by the interface itself which we might or might not choose to override and give a new method definition.

**Bottom line**

Whether to make use of interface or abstract class purely depends on the situational need.